# Matlab launching from terminal but not Openbox

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, matlab, openbox, crunchbang

I have installed Matlab and can run it fine by using the command `matlab` from the terminal but when I try to open it using the Openbox menu GUI the Matlab starting screen appears as normal but then the application seems to close. At the moment the command in Openbox is set to `matlab` but I have also tried the absolute path and running Matlab from there.

Any idea what is causing this?

menu.xml

```
    <item label="Matlab">
        <action name="Execute">
            <command>matlab</command>
        </action>
    </item>
```

Comment: Please post the output of `type -a matlab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember I was puzzled by this one, too, when I first came across it. I don't think its specific to Openbox but probably happens with every launcher where matlab starts without stdout / stdin.

Anyway, the solution is to start matlab with the command:

```
matlab -desktop
```